# using a specific node ID to call a template file

Tags: php, templates, drupal

The standard template for a node in Drupal is `node.tpl.php`

It's possible to call a different template for a content-type, like 'newsitem'. You will call it like this :  `node-newsitem.tpl.php`.

I was wondering if there's a way to call a specific Node ID? `node-34.tpl.php` does **not** work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme's template.php put the following at the top of theme_preprocess_node():
`$vars['template_files'][] = 'node-'. $vars['node']->nid;`

So if your theme is called "myTheme", you might have the following:

```
function myTheme_preprocess_node(&$vars){  
    $vars['template_files'][] = 'node-'. $vars['node']->nid;  
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For **Drupal 7** use this template name (34 - is node ID):

```
node--34.tpl.php
```

And don't forget to clear your cache! More information [on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

Answer (score 0):

I have this working as we speak.  In Drupal 6, my front page is node 5.  It uses

> page-node-5.tpl.php

If it's not loading, consider clearing cache's or rebuilding your theme registry.

Comment: page-node-5.tpl.php is a variant of page.tpl.php, the OP is looking to create variants of node.tpl.php

Comment: Sure, but newsitem-node-34.tpl.php would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I don't follow you.  newsitem-node-34.tpl.php doesn't follow any type of template suggestion pattern in drupal 6 that I'm familiar with.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the d.o article I found it on, but I assure you it's working.  And I couldn't find any additional templates added in Fusion, so I'm not sure!

Answer (score -1):

That naming convention will work, just not by default. Assuming this is Drupal 6, try adding the following code to your theme's template.php:

```
/**
* Override or insert variables into the node templates.
*
* @param $vars
*   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
* @param $hook
*   The name of the template being rendered ("node" in this case.)
*/
function yourthemename_preprocess_node(&$vars, $hook) {
  $node = $vars['node'];
  $vars['template_file'] = 'node-'. $node->nid;
}
```

Make sure you don't try to redeclare `yourthemename_preprocess_node()`--that is, if it already exists in your theme's template.php, just add the $node and $vars['template_file'] lines to it.